# Intellisense inserts wrong word while typing

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, intellisense

When I am typing SQL in Management Studio, sometimes Intellisense makes really obviously bad choices that trip me up, like when I try to type:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Name IS NOT NULL THEN
```

as soon as I hit the space after "IS" it types in

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Name IS_MEMBER ...
```

Is there any way to prevent this? It is very annoying.

Comment: I turned it off for this reason, it was slowing me down.

Comment: I've gotten into the habit of hitting `esc` when typing works I know cause this annoyance.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid that was the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible, use the SQL Server 2012 version of Management Studio. It's much better about this silly stuff. In previous versions I turned it off completely because this annoyed the crap out of me. In 2012 I wouldn't think of turning it off - in addition to being much better about this, it also has partial matching, which means you can type something like:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.index
```

And the completion list will not only list sys.indexes, but also sys.index_columns, sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats, etc. No more needing to know what a name *starts* with. Huzzah!

But if 2012 is not an option, then I agree with @HLGEM - turn it off.